# How to determine how much free space on a drive in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems

I'm using Qt and want a platform-independent way of getting the available free disk space.

I know in Linux I can use `statfs` and in Windows I can use `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`.  I know boost has a way, `boost::filesystem::space(Path const & p)`.

But I don't want those.  I'm in Qt and would like to do it in a Qt-friendly way.

I looked at `QDir`, `QFile`, `QFileInfo` -- nothing!

Comment: Suck it up and use the Windows API, monstrosity that it is.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to and then deal with the Linux version down the road as well.  Joy.

Comment: There's always [APR](https://apr.apache.org/).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I know It's quite old topic but somebody can still find it useful.

Since QT 5.4 the `QSystemStorageInfo` is discontinued, instead there is a new class `QStorageInfo` that makes the whole task really simple and it's cross-platform.

```
QStorageInfo storage = QStorageInfo::root();

qDebug() << storage.rootPath();
if (storage.isReadOnly())
    qDebug() << "isReadOnly:" << storage.isReadOnly();

qDebug() << "name:" << storage.name();
qDebug() << "fileSystemType:" << storage.fileSystemType();
qDebug() << "size:" << storage.bytesTotal()/1024/1024 << "MB";
qDebug() << "availableSize:" << storage.bytesAvailable()/1024/1024 << "MB";
```

> Code has been copied from the example in [QT 5.5 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html#details)

Comment: And the world just got a little bit better. Thanks, @mr.coffee

Comment: "...somebody can still find it useful." Four somebodies so far!

Answer (score 13):

The new [QStorageInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html) class, introduced in Qt 5.4, can do this (and more). It's part of the Qt Core module so no additional dependencies required.

```
#include <QStorageInfo>
#include <QDebug>

void printRootDriveInfo() {
   QStorageInfo storage = QStorageInfo::root();

   qDebug() << storage.rootPath();
   if (storage.isReadOnly())
       qDebug() << "isReadOnly:" << storage.isReadOnly();

   qDebug() << "name:" << storage.name();
   qDebug() << "filesystem type:" << storage.fileSystemType();
   qDebug() << "size:" << storage.bytesTotal()/1024/1024 << "MB";
   qDebug() << "free space:" << storage.bytesAvailable()/1024/1024 << "MB";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing in Qt at time of writing.

Consider commenting on or voting for [QTBUG-3780](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3780).

Comment: It's unfortunate that nothing has changed about this since the mailing list posts I found from 2004/2005.  Voted up on Qt's site.

Comment: And now part of Qt 5.4+!

Answer (score 7):

I wrote this back when I wrote the question (after voting on [QTBUG-3780](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-3780)); I figure I'll save someone (or myself) from doing this from scratch.

This is for Qt 4.8.x.

```
#ifdef WIN32
/*
 * getDiskFreeSpaceInGB
 *
 * Returns the amount of free drive space for the given drive in GB. The
 * value is rounded to the nearest integer value.
 */
int getDiskFreeSpaceInGB( LPCWSTR drive )
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER freeBytesToCaller;
    freeBytesToCaller.QuadPart = 0L;

    if( !GetDiskFreeSpaceEx( drive, &freeBytesToCaller, NULL, NULL ) )
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: Call to GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() failed.";
    }

    int freeSpace_gb = freeBytesToCaller.QuadPart / B_per_GB;
    qDebug() << "Free drive space: " << freeSpace_gb << "GB";

    return freeSpace_gb;
}
#endif
```

Usage:

```
// Check available hard drive space
#ifdef WIN32
        // The L in front of the string does some WINAPI magic to convert
        // a string literal into a Windows LPCWSTR beast.
        if( getDiskFreeSpaceInGB( L"c:" ) < MinDriveSpace_GB )
        {
            errString = "ERROR: Less than the recommended amount of free space available!";
            isReady = false;
        }
#else
#    pragma message( "WARNING: Hard drive space will not be checked at application start-up!" )
#endif
```

Comment: ...its not the Qt-friendly way :) not crossplatform

Comment: @FeritCubukcuoglu Most definitely not but it was what worked at the time.  A new post just came in recent that uses some of the new capabilities of Qt 5.5; it's now the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I need to write to a mounted USB-Stick and I got the available size of memory with the following code:

```
QFile usbMemoryInfo;
QStringList usbMemoryLines;
QStringList usbMemoryColumns;

system("df /dev/sdb1 > /tmp/usb_usage.info");
usbMemoryInfo.setFileName( "/tmp/usb_usage.info" );

usbMemoryInfo.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QTextStream readData(&usbMemoryInfo);

while (!readData.atEnd())
{
    usbMemoryLines << readData.readLine();
}

usbMemoryInfo.close();

usbMemoryColumns = usbMemoryLines.at(1).split(QRegExp("\\s+"));
QString available_bytes = usbMemoryColumns.at(3);
```

Answer (score 4):

I know that this question is already quite old by now, but I searched stackoverflow and found that nobody got solution for this, so I decided to post.

There is **QSystemStorageInfo** class in **QtMobility**, it provides cross-platform way to get info about logical drives. For example: **logicalDrives()** returns list of paths which you can use as parameters for other methods: **availableDiskSpace()**, **totalDiskSpace()** to get free and total drive's space, accordingly, in bytes.

Usage example:

```
QtMobility::QSystemStorageInfo sysStrgInfo;
QStringList drives = sysStrgInfo.logicalDrives();

foreach (QString drive, drives)
{
    qDebug() << sysStrgInfo.availableDiskSpace(drive);
    qDebug() << sysStrgInfo.totalDiskSpace(drive);
}
```

This example prints free and total space in bytes for all logical drives in OS. Don't forget to add **QtMobility** in Qt project file:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += systeminfo
```

I used these methods in a project I'm working on now and it worked for me. Hope it'll help someone!

Answer (score 2):

this code`s working for me:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 //win
    #include "windows.h"
#else //linux
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/statfs.h>
#endif


bool GetFreeTotalSpace(const QString& sDirPath, double& fTotal, double& fFree)
{
    double fKB = 1024;

    #ifdef _WIN32

        QString sCurDir = QDir::current().absolutePath();
        QDir::setCurrent(sDirPath);

        ULARGE_INTEGER free,total;

        bool bRes = ::GetDiskFreeSpaceExA( 0 , &free , &total , NULL );

        if ( !bRes )
            return false;

        QDir::setCurrent( sCurDir );

        fFree = static_cast<__int64>(free.QuadPart)  / fKB;
        fTotal = static_cast<__int64>(total.QuadPart)  / fKB;

    #else // Linux

        struct stat stst;
        struct statfs stfs;

        if ( ::stat(sDirPath.toLocal8Bit(),&stst) == -1 )
            return false;

        if ( ::statfs(sDirPath.toLocal8Bit(),&stfs) == -1 )
            return false;

        fFree = stfs.f_bavail * ( stst.st_blksize / fKB );
        fTotal = stfs.f_blocks * ( stst.st_blksize / fKB );

    #endif // _WIN32

    return true;
}
```