# How to get Total and Used Space of a SD Card in Qt Application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, sd-card

Hi friends I am working on a Qt application where I need to display the total space and used space of a SD Card which is connected to my PC. I need to display them in the form of a string. E.g. 7.6 [GB] or 876 [MB]

Is their a Qt API that can help me achieve it? basically I am looking for an API to whom I can pass the path of the drive and it in-turn gives me the total and used space of the SD Card.

Please help :)

Comment: maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732717/how-to-determine-how-much-free-space-on-a-drive-in-qt) is helpful

Comment: @10WaRRioR01: Thanks for the reply. I do not want to use QtMobility but I see a Windows API `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` which gives Free Space. Is their similar API to get Used Space???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732717/how-to-determine-how-much-free-space-on-a-drive-in-qt), there's no multiplatform way to do this, so Qt doesn't have api for that.
In case you're on windows, you can use [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In your case, to get total *used* space, you substract free space from the total space. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes.... looks like I should get hold of this Windows APi and calculate the space :)