# Does Qt offer a way to get free disk space?

Tags: c++, qt

I am making crossplatform library for my project. I would like the library to include functionality to get free disk space (like [`GetFreeDiskSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364935(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows), but in a cross-platform way. Does Qt provide such functionality?

Comment: Wait a minute, you want to write a *cross-platform* library in *assembly*? Wow, you *certainly* know what you're doing.

Comment: I have project in Windows,I am porting in linux, I want to keep interfaces of MFC libraries same and implementing MFCFROMQT cross platform library, so that same program I can run in both windows as well as linux, So I need to implement GetFreeDiskSpace Function, in this crossplatform library, I don't understand how to start, like shall I use some command line, or use assembly code.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It is a **Qt-specific** question, people. If you don't know anything about Qt, you're not qualified to classify this as a dupe.

Comment: @EOF It appears to have been a simple mis-tagging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine how much free space on a drive in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732717/how-to-determine-how-much-free-space-on-a-drive-in-qt)

Answer (score 1):

[`QStorageInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html), introduced in Qt 5.4, does what you need.

Whatever path you'd pass to `GetFreeDiskSpace`, you simply pass to `QStorageInfo`:

```
#include <QtCore>

int main() {
  QStorageInfo info("C:\\");
  qDebug() << info.rootPath() << "has" << info.bytesFree() << "bytes available.";
  return 0;
}
```